# Docusign - Additional Details for Envelopes using Envelopes::listStatusChanges

Tags: docusignapi

Using the SDK method Envelopes::listStatusChanges, the response object contains the following info for the envelopes:

```
{
  "resultSetSize": "4",
  "totalSetSize": "4",
  "startPosition": "0",
  "endPosition": "3",
  "nextUri": "",
  "previousUri": "",
  "envelopes": [
    {
      "status": "completed",
      "documentsUri": "/envelopes/310d460c-7f34-4b9e-aafd-0f3f1aff18a5/documents",
      "recipientsUri": "/envelopes/310d460c-7f34-4b9e-aafd-0f3f1aff18a5/recipients",
      "envelopeUri": "/envelopes/310d460c-7f34-4b9e-aafd-0f3f1aff18a5",
      "envelopeId": "310d460c-7f34-4b9e-aafd-0f3f1aff18a5",
      "customFieldsUri": "/envelopes/310d460c-7f34-4b9e-aafd-0f3f1aff18a5/custom_fields",
      "notificationUri": "/envelopes/310d460c-7f34-4b9e-aafd-0f3f1aff18a5/notification",
      "statusChangedDateTime": "2016-10-18T14:06:37.6030000Z",
      "documentsCombinedUri": "/envelopes/310d460c-7f34-4b9e-aafd-0f3f1aff18a5/documents/combined",
      "certificateUri": "/envelopes/310d460c-7f34-4b9e-aafd-0f3f1aff18a5/documents/certificate",
      "templatesUri": "/envelopes/310d460c-7f34-4b9e-aafd-0f3f1aff18a5/templates"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I'm looking for a way to include additional fields in the envelope object, namely, `emailSubject`.  It seems like this is possible given the example response under `Generic JSON Response` here: [Envelopes::listStatusChanges](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges/)

If this is not possible via this API method, is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you just need to call the [Envelopes: get](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/get/) API:

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}
```

Here's a sample response:

```
{
    "status": "created",
    "documentsUri": "/envelopes/25d28528-1810-47cf-9c9b-38006e7b9a42/documents",
    "recipientsUri": "/envelopes/25d28528-1810-47cf-9c9b-38006e7b9a42/recipients",
    "attachmentsUri": "/envelopes/25d28528-1810-47cf-9c9b-38006e7b9a42/attachments",
    "envelopeUri": "/envelopes/25d28528-1810-47cf-9c9b-38006e7b9a42",
    "emailSubject": "This is the envelope email subject!",
    "emailBlurb": "This goes in the body.",
    "envelopeId": "25d28528-1810-47cf-9c9b-38006e7b9a42",
    "customFieldsUri": "/envelopes/25d28528-1810-47cf-9c9b-38006e7b9a42/custom_fields",
    "autoNavigation": "true",
    "envelopeIdStamping": "true",
    "notificationUri": "/envelopes/25d28528-1810-47cf-9c9b-38006e7b9a42/notification",
    "enableWetSign": "true",
    "allowMarkup": "false",
    "createdDateTime": "2016-10-24T06:10:48.7300000Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2016-10-24T06:10:48.7300000Z",
    "statusChangedDateTime": "2016-10-24T06:10:48.7300000Z",
    "documentsCombinedUri": "/envelopes/25d28528-1810-47cf-9c9b-38006e7b9a42/documents/combined",
    "certificateUri": "/envelopes/25d28528-1810-47cf-9c9b-38006e7b9a42/documents/certificate",
    "templatesUri": "/envelopes/25d28528-1810-47cf-9c9b-38006e7b9a42/templates",
    "brandId": "e6b54dbf-bba2-4ea2-91c0-bbcc90e1fd2b",
    "purgeState": "unpurged",
    "is21CFRPart11": "false",
    "isSignatureProviderEnvelope": "false"
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId} since this counts against the 15 min API limit for a specific envelope?  https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#api-rules